# android-support-v7-appcompat has same attrs as actionbarsherlock library

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-support-library, google-cast

I'm trying to get chromecast integration in my app but I'm having build issues when I add the android-support-v7-appcompat to my project.  Basically it has an attrs.xml file that has the same values as the actionbarsherlock attrs.xml file.  Is there anyway around this?  This seems kind of ridiculous that different libraries can possibly conflict resource values.

Comment: I understand that there was an update to ActionBarSherlock to deal w/ this.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No not yet.  This is brutal.  Les Vogel, if I just update actionbarsherlock will this get fixed?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/999

Comment: Hey Les Vogel.  Do you know if there's any way we can workaround this?  From what I can see, it seems like I can't build this with actionbarsherlock.  Maybe I can just build this without the MediaRouteButton.

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter the same problem and had a hard time for several hours figuring this out. this is how I solved it.

**You usually need support-v7-appcompat if your minimum sdk supported is below API14.**

1. I removed support-v7-appcompat as my library. (This will show error regarding missing theme.)
2. For **all** the styles.xml in all folders (mine are) values, values-v11 and values-v14

   style name="AppBaseTheme" **parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"**

   replace it with

   style name="AppBaseTheme" **parent="android:Theme.Light"**
3. for some reason, in my menu xml file. it had error for android:showAsAction. I was able to solve it by deleting it then save and then copying the same thing from another file i have because I want that function. (Really weird it was just the same text.)
4. I did my sherlock code adjustments needed for my app

**I am now able to run actionbar in 2.3.3**