# ActionBarSherlock conflicts with Appcompat

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I am trying to do a small test project using ActionBarSherlock library but having the same issue as in this post -> [android-support-v7-appcompat has same attrs as actionbarsherlock library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903101/android-support-v7-appcompat-has-same-attrs-as-actionbarsherlock-library)

Ref: http://pastebin.com/ERDHsQbe

Has anyone found a solution yet?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove support-v7-appcompat library from your project, its in build with sherlock .
Then in the styles.xml change `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to 
`parent="android:Theme.Light"` .This will be sufficient .

If you are gettin any errors related to android-support-v4 , try and copy the latest android-support-v4 into the Sherlock library folder in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since I changed attributes in attr.xml file which is identical to another attributes in support-v7-appcompat library
and changing every thing related to it in the actionbarshelock project manually
I lost much of time but finally I did it
replace your ActionBarSherlock library by this one

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-XiEeIClMuTb2t3S0h0d2lsUUE/view?usp=sharing

the only change is in the attr.xml file and it's reflection on the java code and layouts

note : you must be sure that you have only one android-support-v4 library file to avoid jar mismatch

Comment: Thank you Shehab, after many days of trial and error, its working now.